# I am getting IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-redux, stripe-payments

I am following a Amazon clone guide to get me started with React JS. While being 4 days in im getting stuck after processing my Orders. I am using Stripe, Firebase, Axios and Express to do this. After clicking the Buy now button im getting the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string. You specified: true.

Tried every possible solution and the videoguide doesnt get this error or discuss this error in anyway.

Thanks in advance!

I wouldnt mind sharing my github so youre getting a full look at all my codes if need be.

This is my payment page code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import "./Payment.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import axios from "./axios";
import {db} from "./firebase";

function Payment() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const history = useHistory();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false);
  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    //zorgt ervoor dat ik betalingen kan aannemen
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
      });
      setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
    };

    getClientSecret();
  }, [basket]);

  console.log("Mijn geheim is >>>>", clientSecret);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // Stripe betalingen
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        // betalingconfirmatie

        // bestelhistorie uit mijn database halen
        db.collection('users')
        .doc(user?.id)
        .collection('orders')
        .doc(paymentIntent.id)
        .set({
          basket: basket,
          amount: paymentIntent.amount,
          created: paymentIntent.created
        })


        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY_BASKET",
        });

        history.replace("/orders");
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // Kijkt naar veranderingen in de Cardelement
    // geeft errors aan wanneer de bezoeker zijn kaartgegevens niet goed intypt
    setDisabled(event.emtpy);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  };

  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="paymentcontainer">
        <h1>
          Checkout (<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>)
        </h1>

        {/* payment*/}
        <div className="paymentsection">
          <div className="paymenttitle">
            <h3>Bezorgadres</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="paymentaddress">
            <p>{user?.email}</p>
            <p>Melkdistel</p>
            <p>Almere, FL</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* payment*/}
        <div className="paymentsection">
          <div className="paymenttitle">
            <h3>Artikelen</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="paymentitems">
            {basket.map((item) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                image={item.image}
                price={item.price}
                rating={item.rating}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* payment*/}
        <div className="paymentsection">
          <div className="paymenttitle">
            <h3>Betalingsmethode</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="paymentdetails">
            {/* Stripe */}

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <CardElement onChange={handleChange} />

              <div className="paymentpriceContainer">
                <CurrencyFormat
                  renderText={(value) => <h3>Order Totaal:{value}</h3>}
                  decimalScale={2}
                  value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                  displayType={"text"}
                  thousandSeparator={true}
                  prefix={"$"}
                />
                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                  <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                </button>
              </div>

              {/*Errors */}
              {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

This is my index.js code or my server:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_xxx");

// API

// App config
const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(express.json());

// API Routes
app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;

  console.log("Payment request received", total);

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total,
    currency: "usd",
  });

  // Good
  response.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

// Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

// http://localhost:5001/flowerpower-7c9f1/us-central1/api
```

[image: Console Prtscrn]

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please don't share your Stripe secret keys!

The issue is that you're passing `clientSecret: true` to the [`confirmCardPayment`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) method, which instead expects the `client_secret` of a created [PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret).

I note from the code you've provided that `true` is the default value of your `clientSecret` local React variable used in the `confirmCardPayment` call. The error you're seeing likely indicates that this value is not updated (via `setClientSecret`) following your API call to `/payments/create`.

My recommendation to you would be verify that the `/payments/create` API does indeed create and return a `PaymentIntent` object and introduce error handling to your sever function to throw if/when that Stripe API call fails.

Comment: Damn you were totally right about the stripe key, forgot to put it away thanks for the edit. Secondly can you simplify what you just said, im quite new to stripe and react still

Comment: @HichamHarmaz It's right there in the screenshot you've added. The API call to your Express app (`await axios({ method: "post", url: '/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}'})`) is throwing an error. Looks to be network related? I would start there. Because that's throwing an error, there's no PaymentIntent created with Stripe and the `clientSecret` variable you're passing to `confirmCardPayment` is never updated from its default value (which is `true`).